# Большая картинка по центру при различных разрешениях, без использования background (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Структура страницы сверху-вниз:

1. Шапка сайта ширина 800px выровнена по середине.
2. картинка 1400х400px выровнена по середине, если окно браузера, например, 1000 px, то часть картинки скрывается по ОБОИМ краям, т.е. картинка остается по центру, а справа и слева скрывается по 200px. При этом скрол не должен появиться.
3. остальной контент ширина 800px выровнен по середине.

C помощью `background` я знаю как так сделать, но нужно это сделать для картинки в теге img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться хитрым трюком с двумя контейнерами http://jsfiddle.net/pn5J2/ .

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.bg-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg-container1 {
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bg-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
    <div class="bg-container1">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="bg-image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уже нашел похожий на ваш вариант, до конца не доделал, но на первый взгляд получается вот с этим:

.c1{width:1400px;position:relative;float:left;left:50%}
.c2{width:1400px;position:relative;float:left;left:-50%}

Comment: В моем варианте не надо указывать width, он автоматически меняется в зависимости от ширины картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите использовать свойство `background`, я предлагаю обратиться к тегу `img` по атрибуту.

```
img[src="../img/ваша-широкая-картинка.png"] {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть опоздал с ответом, но вот вариант с jQuery (**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/QdLew/2/embedded/result/)**):

**css**

```
#header{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#header, #content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
#tricky-image {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="header">Блоки шириной 300 пикселей<br>Картинка шириной 450 пикселей</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что новая модель организационной деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.</p>
    <div id="tricky-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1400x400" alt="" /></div>
    <p>С другой стороны консультация с широким активом влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации.</p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var max_width = 800, //ширина контента
    image_width = 1400, //ширина картинки
    resize_timer = null,
    resize_timout = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){
    changePosition();
});

$(window).bind('resize', function() {       
    if(resize_timer) {
        clearTimeout(resize_timer);
    }
    resize_timer = setTimeout(changePosition(), resize_timout);
});

function changePosition(){
    var window_width = $(window).width(),
    holder = $('#tricky-image'),
    img = $('#tricky-image > img:first-child'),
    holder_margin_left = Math.ceil((window_width - max_width) / 2),
    img_margin_left = Math.ceil((image_width - window_width) / 2);
    console.log(window_width);
    if (window_width < image_width) {
        holder
        .width(window_width)
        .css({"margin-left": "-" + holder_margin_left + "px"});
        img.css({"margin-left": "-" + img_margin_left + "px"});
    }
}
```